# Getting Account name in VaultCustomQuery

Tags: corda

I am trying to get some aggregated data from Corda and am using the Accounts module.

**My State:**

```
    @BelongsToContract(InvoiceContractTk::class)
class SMInvoiceStateTk constructor(val amount: Amount<Currency>,
                                   val issuedDate : LocalDateTime,
                                   val amountPaid: Amount<IssuedTokenType>,
                                   val paidFrom : Party?,
                                   val seller: AnonymousParty,
                                   val buyer: AnonymousParty,
                                   val typeOfGoods : String,
                                   val quantity : Int,                                   
                                   val paidDate : LocalDateTime?,
                                   val nettAmountReceived: Amount<Currency>,
                                   override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier) : LinearState, QueryableState {
    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(amount: Amount<Currency>,
                issuedDate: LocalDateTime,
                amountPaid: Amount<IssuedTokenType>,
                paidFrom : Party? = amountPaid.token.issuer,
                seller: AnonymousParty,
                buyer: AnonymousParty,
                typeOfGoods: String,
                quantity: Int,
                paidDate: LocalDateTime?,
                linearId: UniqueIdentifier) :
            this(amount,
                    issuedDate,
                    amountPaid,
                    paidFrom,
                    seller,
                    buyer,
                    typeOfGoods,
                    quantity,
                    Amount(0, amount.token),
                    paidDate,
                    Amount(0, amount.token),
                    linearId
) {    }
    /**
     * Participants , seller, buyer
     */
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() = listOf(seller, buyer).map { it }
    
        /**
     * Generates a Mapped Object of State
     *
     * @param schema
     */
    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
        return when (schema) {
            is SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1 -> SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1.PersistantSMTkInvoice(
                    this.linearId.toString(),
                    this.amount.toDecimal(),
                    this.issuedDate,
                    this.amountPaid.toDecimal(),
                    this.paidFrom.toString(),
                    this.seller,
                    this.buyer,
                    this.typeOfGoods,
                    this.quantity,
                    this.paidDate,
                    this.nettAmountReceived.toDecimal()
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Supported schemas for this object
     */
    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1)
```

**Schema:**

```
/**
 * The Database Schema to hold a record of an [SMInvoiceTkSchema]
 */
object SMInvoiceTkSchema

/**
 * Defines the fields for an [SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1]
 */
object SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1 : MappedSchema (
        schemaFamily = SMInvoiceTkSchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes = listOf(SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1.PersistantSMTkInvoice::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name ="sm_tkinvoice_states")
    /**
     * Table SM_INVOICE_STATES
     *
     * @property invoiceId the id of the Invoice
     * @property amount the amount of the invoice
     * @property issuedDate the date the invoice was issued
     * @property amountPaid the amount has been paid
     * @property paidFrom the CBDC account from which theinvoice was paid
     * @property seller the seller of the goods on the invoice
     * @property buyer the buyer of the goods
     * @property typeOfGoods the type of goods purchased
     * @property quantity the quantity of goods purchased
     * @property paidDate   the date the invoice was paid
     * @property nettAmountReceived the amount received by the seller after paying the VAT
     */
    class PersistantSMTkInvoice(

            @Column(name="invoice_Id")
            var invoiceId: String,
            @Column(name="amount")
            var amount: BigDecimal,
            @Column(name="issuedDate")
            var issuedDate: LocalDateTime,
            @Column(name="amountPaid")
            var amountPaid: BigDecimal,
            @Column(name="paidFrom")
            var paidFrom: String,
            @Column(name="seller")
            var seller: AbstractParty?,
            @Column(name="buyer")
            var buyer: AbstractParty?,
            @Column(name="typeOfGoods")
            var typeOfGoods: String,
            @Column(name="quantity")
            var quantity: Int,
            @Column(name="paidDate")
            var paidDate: LocalDateTime?,
            @Column(name="nettAmountreceived")
            var nettAmountReceived: BigDecimal
    )
        : PersistentState() {
        /**
         * Default constructor required by hibernate.
         */
        constructor(): this(
                "",
                BigDecimal.ZERO,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                BigDecimal.ZERO,
               "",
                null,
                null,
                "",
                0,
                null,
                BigDecimal.ZERO
        )
    }
}
```

This all works fine for issuing an paying an invoice and running some queries. I now want to run 2 other aggregate queries which amount to:

```
SELECT buyer,typeOfGoods,Round(SUM(amountPaid),2)
From SM_TKINVOICE_STATES
Group by buyer,typeOfGoods
```

And

```
select typeOfGoods,seller,round(SUM(nettAmountReceived),2)
from SM_TKINVOICE_STATES
group by typeOfGoods,seller
```

**strong text**
Where buyer would be the Account Names e.g. Alice, Jim, Fred and for sellers MegaCorp, MiniCorp etc.

My problem is that I can only seem to aggregate queries against the Persisted schema and for buyer and seller this holds the CordaX500 name, i.e. the node NOT the account.  No matter what I put in the uyer and seller fields all that is stored is the node ( I believe this is by design)

How do I get a resut set like:

```
 Alice   Adult Clothing         52.60
 Alice   Books                  34.10
 Alice   Children's Clothing    84.68
 Bob     Adult Clothing         31.16
 Bob     Alcohol                41.40
 George  Energy                 101.44
 Jim     Groceries              52.82
 Jim     Electrical             46.79
 Jim     Energy                 112.12
 Kathy   Adult Clothing         40.72
 Alice   Alcohol                38.45
 Alice   Children's car seat    40.15
 Alice   Electrical             41.93
 Alice   Groceries              56.30
 Alice   Energy                 62.68
 Anne    Adult Clothing         17.95
 Anne    Alcohol                10.79
 Anne    Books                  5.68
 Anne    Children's Clothing    57.98
 Anne    Children's car seat    31.42
 Anne    Electrical             60.98
 Anne    Groceries              64.68
 Anne    Energy                 37.31
 Bob     Books                  27.95
 Bob     Children's Clothing    41.92
 Bob     Children's car seat    45.07
 Bob     Electrical 59.23
...
```

and

```
 Adult Clothing             MegaCompany     234.81
 Books                      MediumCompany   230.45
 Children's Clothing        MediumCompany   291.78
 Alcohol                    MegaCompany     194.02
 Energy                     ElectricAndGas  573.24
 Groceries                  SmallBusiness   258.37
 Electrical                 SmallBusiness   242.74
 Children's car seat        MiniCompamy     248.37
 Electrical                 MiniCompamy     208.11
 Groceries                  SoleTrader      317.32
 Children's Clothing        SoleTrader      186.74
```

**My Flow:**

```
   @Suspendable
    override fun call(): List<Any> {

        val buyerNode = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(CordaX500Name(organisation = "BuyerCWP",locality = "London",country = "GB"))!!.legalIdentities[0]
        val sellerNode = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(CordaX500Name(organisation = "SellerCWP",locality = "Glasgow",country = "GB"))!!.legalIdentities[0]

        val buyerAccounts = subFlow(AccountsForHost(buyerNode))
        val sellerAccountsForHost =  subFlow(AccountsForHost(sellerNode))

        val buyerIds  = buyerAccounts.map {it.state.data.linearId.id}

        val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(
                status = Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED
        )

        val sum = builder {SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1.PersistantSMTkInvoice::amountPaid.sum(groupByColumns = listOf(SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1.PersistantSMTkInvoice::buyer  ,SMInvoiceTkSchemaV1.PersistantSMTkInvoice::typeOfGoods))}
        val sumCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(sum)

        val allStates = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(
                contractStateType = SMInvoiceStateTk::class.java,
                criteria = criteria
                        .and( sumCriteria)
                //**************  SOMETHING HERE I THINK TO MAP TO ACCOUNT NAMES ************************
        )

        val otherRes = allStates.otherResults
       return otherRes
    }
```

This gives me :

```
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Adult Clothing, 221.79,
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Alcohol, 213.40,
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Books, 526.20, 
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Children's Clothing, 261.40, 
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Children's car seat, 547.47, 
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Electrical, 541.72, 
O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB, Energy, 561.94
...
```

Obvoiusly O=BuyerCWP, L=London, C=GB should be Alice, Jim, Bob etc.

What do I need to do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use something like this to get the list of one's accounts

```
val myAccounts = accountService.ourAccounts().map { it.state.data.name }
```

and then use it in the query criteria

```
QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(externalIds = listOf(myAccount.identifier.id))
```

Try to take a look to the workflow tests from [the samples-kotlin/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking/workflows/src/test/kotlin/com/t20worldcup/FlowTests.kt) , I think you will find good examples of what you need.